# Trouble using django.template Context in unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-1.3

I got a little confusing situation here when I use the Context from django.template.

The following works in the python shell:

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> b=Template('TEST').render(Context())
>>> print b
TEST
```

When I use the very same Code in a unittest, I get the follwing Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/newsletterapi/tests.py", line 25, in setUp
    b = Template('TEST').render(Context())
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 121, in render
    context.render_context.push()
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'render_context'
```

The unittest looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myproject.newsletterapi.models import Newsletter
from django.utils.termcolors import colorize
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.template import Template, Context
import random
import datetime
from decimal import *
import string


class NewsletterTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        b = Template('TEST').render(Context()) # this is line 25
        self.newsletter = Newsletter(body=b)
        self.newsletter.save()

### ... continues here
```

Does anyone have an idea why this works in the shell but not in the unittest? I appreciate every hint.

Comment: In what kind of shell does the first example run? This needs settings to work (DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE), so maybe that's what you're missing in your unit test.

Comment: I use this command inside my project dir for the shell:
python2.7 manage.py shell

Comment: And the unit test? You need to run that in the same context

Comment: python2.7 manage.py test newsletterapi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, i got the solution:

```
from decimal import *
```

is the "bad One" this lib has a Context object too.
Thanks for anyone reading!

Comment: Cheers :)! Good to see it saved you some time and nerves.